# How do I create a table using 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

[image]

Hi :)

I need to create a table for seats and rows of a movie theatre (like the one in the picture) but I can't figure out how to print the row numbers on the left side. I've managed to put together the seats and the numbers on the upper side of the table but I am failing at adding the column with numbers on the left side. Maybe you guys could give me some advice? Here is the code!

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int row = scanner.nextInt();
int seat = scanner.nextInt();

char[][] array = new char[row][seat];

System.out.print("  ");
for (int i = 1; i < seat + 1; i++)
    System.out.print(i + " ");
    
System.out.println();

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.print("  ");
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++)
        System.out.print('S' + " ");

    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more like simple programming problem than java question. There are many ugly solutions used, but will try to follow convention used by you.

Think about arrays and loops that you are using step by step. First loop

```
for (int i = 1; i < seat + 1; i++) {
        if (i == 1) {
            System.out.print("  ");
        }
        System.out.print(i + " ");
}
```

Counting from 0 is prefered way but this loop just fills first row with numbers.

In second loop `i` is still your row counter, and `j` is just a column counter:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
            if (j == 0) {
                System.out.print("  ");
            }
            System.out.print('S' + " ");
        }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Your question truly is: how to write numbers in first column row by row. There is a simple answer to this using code you just provided. In your code if column  `j` is equal to 0 then you are just writing empty space now, but instead you want to write row number `i`. I hope that will give you a clue. Try to solve it by yourself. If you still won't be able then:

> Change if body of second for in second loop to System.out.print(i + " ");